# How to use qmake file with google test and shared library

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

I started with a makefile that would generate the dependencies of my C++ files.  It was a C++ project using google test.  Later, I started a Qt project which uses qmake and links to a shared library which the old makefile builds.  Needless to say, the old makefile is really complicated now.

I would like to make a qmake file which can do the following:

- Build a shared library for a list a sources
- Build google test (optionally, I would accept a separate makefile for this)
- Build my Qt executable with a different list of sources linking to the first shared library
- All builds should have debug and release versions which will output to different directories

Can someone point me in the right direction for making a *.pro file which will do that?  I'm really not clear on how to do things like multiple targets in qmake.

Here is the current makefile I am using (clearly a mess):

```
GTEST_DIR = /home/matt/lib/gtest-1.5.0
GMOCK_DIR = /home/matt/lib/gmock-1.5.0
SRC_DIR = /home/matt/Documents/myproject

QTINC := -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore \
    -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4

TEST_SRCS = test/TestRunner.cpp test/CellTest.cpp test/PuzzleTest.cpp \
    test/SingleCandidateMethodTest.cpp test/ExclusionMethodTest.cpp \
    test/BlockIntersectionMethodTest.cpp test/CoveringSetMethodTest.cpp \
    test/SimpleValidatorTest.cpp test/PuzzleMarkerTest.cpp \
    test/PlayerValidatorTest.cpp test/SolverHelperTest.cpp \
    test/GuessCommandTest.cpp test/MarkCommandTest.cpp \
    test/UnmarkCommandTest.cpp test/MethodSolverTest.cpp \
    test/SimplePuzzleImporterTest.cpp test/SolvedPuzzleImporterTest.cpp \
    test/AddHintMarksCommandTest.cpp test/CellControllerTest.cpp \
    test/PuzzleControllerTest.cpp
QT_SRCS = 
LIB_SRCS = Puzzle.cpp Cell.cpp SingleCandidateMethod.cpp ExclusionMethod.cpp \
    BlockIntersectionMethod.cpp CoveringSetMethod.cpp SimpleValidator.cpp \
    PuzzleMarker.cpp PlayerValidator.cpp SolverHelper.cpp GuessCommand.cpp \
    MarkCommand.cpp UnmarkCommand.cpp MethodSolver.cpp \
    SimplePuzzleImporter.cpp SolvedPuzzleImporter.cpp GameManager.cpp \
    CellController.cpp AddHintMarksCommand.cpp GameController.cpp \
    PuzzleController.cpp

DEPDIR = .deps
df = $(DEPDIR)/$(@F)

# preprocessor
CPPFLAGS += -I$(GTEST_DIR)/include -I$(GMOCK_DIR)/include -I$(SRC_DIR) $(QTINC)

# C++ compiler
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++0x
# qt defines
QTDEF = -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
# stuff to link for Qt
QTFLAGS = -L/usr/lib -lQtCore -lQtGui -lpthread

# gtest headers, don't need to change
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
                $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h
# gmock stuff, don't need to change
GMOCK_HEADERS = $(GMOCK_DIR)/include/gmock/*.h \
                $(GMOCK_DIR)/include/gmock/internal/*.h \
                $(GTEST_HEADERS)

MAKEDEPEND = $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -o $(df).d $<
MAKEDEPEND_TEST = $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -o $(df).d -MT $(basename $<).o $<
MAKEDEPEND_QT = $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM -o $(df).d -MT $(basename $<).o $<

SRCS := main.cpp $(LIB_SRCS)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
LIB_OBJS := $(LIB_SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
QT_OBJS := $(QT_SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
TEST_OBJS := $(TEST_SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)

# targets:
debug : CXXFLAGS += -g -O0
# removed this warning because it sucks: -Wconversion (int to size_t!)
debug_warn : CXXFLAGS += -pedantic -Wextra 
debug_warn : debug
debug : all
release : CXXFLAGS += -O2
release : all

lib : CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
lib : libSudokuLib.so

libSudokuLib.so : $(LIB_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -o libSudokuLib.so $(LIB_OBJS)

all : sudoku run_tests

sudoku : $(OBJS) $(QT_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(QTDEF) $(CXXFLAGS) $(QTFLAGS) $^ -o $@

run_tests : $(LIB_OBJS) $(TEST_OBJS) gtest.a gmock.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@

# dependency stuff
.D_TARGET:
    mkdir -p $(DEPDIR)
    touch $@

.PRECIOUS: .D_TARGET

# GTEST building stuff don't touch me
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
GMOCK_SRCS_ = $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GMOCK_HEADERS)

gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
           $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc

gmock-all.o : $(GMOCK_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) \
            -c $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/gmock-all.cc

gmock_main.o : $(GMOCK_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) \
            -c $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/gmock_main.cc

gmock.a : gmock-all.o gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
           $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc

gtest.a : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gtest_main.a : gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

# QT stuff
%Qt.o : %Qt.o .D_TARGET
    $(MAKEDEPEND_QT);
    @cp $(df).d $(df).P;
#   sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
#       -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(df).d >> $(df).P; 
    @rm -f $(df).d
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(QTDEF) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# tests
%Test.o : %Test.cpp .D_TARGET $(GMOCK_HEADERS)
    $(MAKEDEPEND_TEST);
    @cp $(df).d $(df).P;
#   sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
#       -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(df).d >> $(df).P; 
    @rm -f $(df).d
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# objects from sources
%.o : %.cpp .D_TARGET
    $(MAKEDEPEND);
    @cp $(df).d $(df).P; \
#   sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
#       -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(df).d >> $(df).P; 
    @rm -f $(df).d
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

-include $(QT_SRCS:%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)/%.o.P)
-include $(TEST_SRCS:test/%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)/%.o.P)
-include $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)/%.o.P)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(TEST_OBJS) $(QT_OBJS) \
        gtest.a gtest_main.a gtest-all.o gtest_main.o \
        .D_TARGET sudoku run_tests
    rm -rf $(DEPDIR)
```

And here is the project.pro file for qmake (which relies on that first makefile instead of building the library itself)

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = qtsudoku
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += . ../myproject
CONFIG += qt warn_on debug
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
LIBS += -L/home/matt/Documents/myproject -lSudokuLib

# Input
HEADERS += QtPuzzleModel.h QtPuzzleView.h QtGameApplication.h QtDirector.h \
    QtMainWindow.h QtFactory.h
SOURCES += main.cpp QtPuzzleModel.cpp QtGameApplication.cpp QtDirector.cpp \
    QtMainWindow.cpp QtFactory.cpp
```

Comment: As funny as it might sound I find using `cmake` instead of `qmake` much easier and more readable. Especially with recent updates of `cmake` it takes literally seconds to setup such a project.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a good way to do something like this is with the SUBDIRS qmake template.  You would make a qmake file for each of the items you want to build (shared library, google test, and the executable), then make a SUBDIRS template to do those in order.  I think the subdirs template will provide the debug/release flags to each underlying make file.

For the shared library, the [qmake library template](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-common-projects.html#building-a-library) should be fine.

I don't know about google test, I assume you could generate a qmake file for it if desired, or you could continue with the makefile.

For linking the two, you could make a qmake file that has a main.cpp, specifies the others as libraries, and [builds an executable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-common-projects.html#building-an-application).

You can use [DESTDIR](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#destdir), [MOC_DIR](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#moc-dir), [OBJECTS_DIR](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#objects-dir), and [UI_DIR](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#ui-dir) to change where generated files go.